# Code first entity framework inheritance

Tags: entity-framework

I am using entity framework to build a data driven app. I have a base class which has lots is shared properties such as timestamp,Id,creator etc and I subclass this for all of my actual objects.. Is this a good design? Is there a limit to the amount of entities I can create like this?

Comment: There are different schemes to model inheritance in EF. Each has trade-offs. Here's a good place to start http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good design. It would be bad design, of course, if Entity Framework didn't support inheritance as an ORM feature. But it does!

As far as I know, there is no practical limit to the number of entities you can define and use in Entity Framework.